# ignore rule on block

Tags: sonarjs

Like with sonar-java and the annotation @SuppressWarnings("squid:S2078"),
is there any way with sonar-js to ignore one rule on a block of code ??
The git repo doesn't have any exemple of that.

I develop a react-redux ES6 app and i have reducer with default value :

```
export default function myReducer(prev = initialState, action)
```

and Sonar complain with "Function parameters with default values should be last".
But i can't change the order of the parameters of a reducer and i need a default value.

Answer (score 5):

The options you have:

- in your project administration in SQ you can set up ignoring some files for some rule (see [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus))
- you mark issues in SQ as "won't fix"
- you put "// NOSONAR" comment in the line with issue

You can also report false-positive issue in [SonarJS github issues](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript/issues/new).

Comment: So, there is no solution like in sonar-java.
Ok, thanks